# i need to program this code with arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, processing

anything i do seems to break down my code into unusable rubbish. Note that it is also a mess... but at least it does work almost properly.
Here are some details:
it's sort of a particle system but with images. koffer stands for bag and it has to be a sort of eplosion of rotating bags that get slightly bigger or smaller for the depth effect and they fade away in time and after leaving the screen it should be deleted.
For now i got half of the bags that explode to turn random ways and half of the bags don't do that. They all fade but don't get deleted after leaving the screen. there is no slight resize yet. But most of all i have to use an arraylist() and don't know how to implement that. 
here is my code:

Main Class BagEplode:

```
PImage coffre;
float life = 255;
int i = 0;
Ball [] balls = new Ball [200];


void setup(){
  size (600,600,P3D);
  noStroke();
  smooth();
  coffre = loadImage("coffre.png");
  for (i = 0; i < balls.length; i ++)
  {
    balls[i] = new Ball();
  }
}

void draw()
{
  clear();
  life -= 2.5;

  for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
 {
   if(i <= 4)
   {
   balls[i].kleur();
    image(coffre, balls[i].x, balls[i].y);
    tint(255, life);
    balls[i].update();
   }
   //else
   //{
   //}

 }

}
```

and i got the Class Ball:

```
class Ball
{
public void kleur(){

}

  float x = width/2;
  float y = 601;
  float vX = random(1,4);
  float vY = random(-9,-5);
  float sizeX = 0 ;
  float sizeY = 0 ;
  float draaiHoek = 0;
  float angle = random(-3,3);

 public void update(){
   x += vX ;
   y += vY ;
   vY += 0.125;
   sizeX = 64 ;
   sizeY = 64 ;
   draaiHoek -=angle;
   imageMode(CENTER);
   pushMatrix();
   translate(x,y);
   rotate((radians(draaiHoek)));
   image(coffre, 0, 0);
   imageMode(CORNER);
   popMatrix();

   //if (x > width || x < 0 || y > height || y < 0)
   //{

   //}

 }
}
```

Thanx for helping me in advance. I hope i really can get some pointers.

Comment: Posting code that actually compiles _might_ help. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you need to replace **balls** array of type- **Ball** with an ArrayList of type **Ball**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ball {

    PImage coffre;
    float life = 255;
    int i = 0;


    //Ball [] balls = new Ball [200];
    ArrayList<Ball> balls= new ArrayList<Ball>();

    void setup(){
      size (600,600,P3D);
      noStroke();
      smooth();
      coffre = loadImage("coffre.png");


/*    for (i = 0; i < balls.length; i ++)
      {
        balls[i] = new Ball();
      }
*/

      for(int i=0;i<balls.size();i++)
         {

             balls.add(new Ball());
         }
    }

    void draw()
    {
      clear();
      life -= 2.5;

/*    for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
     {
       if(i <= 4)
       {
       balls[i].kleur();
        image(coffre, balls[i].x, balls[i].y);
        tint(255, life);
        balls[i].update();
       }
*/        
      for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++)
         {
           if(i <= 4)
           {
           balls.get(i).kleur();
            image(coffre, balls.get(i).x, balls.get(i).y);
            tint(255, life);
            balls.get(i).update();
           }
       //else
       //{
       //}
     }
    }
}
```